# Comma code - automate the boring stuff with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working through an exercise of Chapter 4 from [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/), which reads as follows:

> "Say you have a list value like this: spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it."

Please excuse me for any mistakes I make here cuz this is my first time using stack overflow and also me being an absolute beginner in python.
so I ended up writing this piece of code which gives out some random stuff would you please tell me where did I go wrong and how could I fix the code in the logic I intended to..

```
def proj(some):
    k=0
    t=""
    for i in some:
        if k<= (len(some)-2): 
            t = i + ', '
            k += 1
        else:
            t = t + 'and ' + i
    print(t)

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

proj(spam)
```

My logic here was i keep two counters that is k(for counting which word in the list i currently added) and t(the base string where i will add the words from the given list).
Now my idea was that I iterate each element through the list and count each element with k, and keep doing that until the if condition no longer satisfies because we are on the last element as the k counter suggests we go to else loop and print 'and' + last element and exit and print it out.
That was my thought process please guide me where exactly am I messing this up?
(sorry for bad English)

I tired this:

```
def proj(some):
    k=0
    t=""
    for i in some:
        if k<= (len(some)-2):
            t = i + ', '
            k += 1
        else:
            t = t + 'and ' + i
    print(t)

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

proj(spam)
```

expected this:
apples, bananas, tofu and cats

resulted this:
tofu, and cats

Comment: In your first `t = ` you forgot `t = t + ...` so you override it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
def stringify_list(l):
    s = ""
    for idx, item in enumerate(l):
        if idx == len(l) - 1:
            s += 'and ' + item
            break
        s += item + ', '
    return s

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
stringify_list(spam)
```

Output:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```